# Controlling low DC voltage with high AC voltage

Tags: switches, relay, control, motor-controller

I replaced my existing manual roller blind switches with Wi-Fi-enabled touch ones and I'm facing an issue with properly fitting them in my setup.

The manual roller blind switches operated on 16 VDC supplied by [Somfy 2 AC Motor Controller](https://service.somfy.com/downloads/buildings/ibplus_2ac-moco_ds_201303281.pdf) installed at the distribution board in my hallway. The new touch switches, however, output 230 VAC and I'm trying to figure out how to proceed.

This is how the initial configuration looked like:
[image: Initial configuration]

The 16 VDC control signals were transmitted over telecommunications cables (4 x 0.8 mm diameter lines each). I'm guessing it would not be safe to use these cables to transmit 230 VAC instead? Even if it was only to control remote relays and not power any real load, as pictured below?

[image: Variant 1]

Another option I see is to place the relays in the junction boxes like this:

[image: Variant 2]

But I think that fitting them in there would present a challenge due to very limited space.

How should I go about this? Let me add that the touch switch manufacturer does not offer any low voltage-rated ones, nor could I find any alternatives online. Also, at this point, I'm unable to lay any additional wires between the distribution board and the junction boxes.

If I were to use relays as in the above diagrams, what type / model should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two 230 VAC-rated electromagnetic relays for each roller blind switch and it's working perfectly so far. Fitting them into the switch boxes was quite a challenge but I was fortunate enough to have some available space in the adjacent ones.

Used relays: [Zamel PEP-01/230](https://zamel.com/en-GB/products/exta-building-automation/electromagnetic-relays/pep-01230)

Wiring diagram:
[image: Wiring diagram]

Answer (score 0):

The relay switching scheme is fine. 230V~ relays with gold plated SPDT contacts and relay bases with screw-type terminals would be required.

Comment: Thanks! Posted by final solution [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/504771/241075).